# How can I fix this Python code that does not run?

Tags: python, init

I believe the positioning is wrong:

```
name = (input("Please enter your name "))
if name=="Matthew":
    class Students:
        def __init__(self, name, age, grade):
            self.name = name
            self.age = age
            self.grade = grade
        
        
        def greeting(self):
            print("hello", self.name.title() ,"you are", self.age, "of age, in grade", self.grade) 
            
        stud1 = Students("Matthew", "13", "6")
        stud1.greeting()       
            
else:
    ("no")
```

The first part runs, it asks for your name which is inputted by then the program ends

Comment: What do you try to do that doesn't work ? Also pur your class definition outside of that code

Comment: You're defining a class inside your `if` (which is rather unusual) but that's all you're doing. You never create an instance of it or call any of its functions.

Comment: `class students` which includes the `__init__` and `greeting` function should be at the beginning.

Comment: The class definition would raise an error because you're trying to call `Students("Matthew", "13", "6")` before the definition of `Students` is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that you put `stud1` inside class and I think you forgot `print()` function in `else:` statement.

```py
class Students:
    def __init__(self, name, age, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.grade = grade

    def greeting(self):
        print("hello", self.name.title(), "you are", self.age, "of age, in grade", self.grade)

name = (input("Please enter your name "))
if name == "Matthew":
    stud1 = Students("Matthew", "13", "6")
    stud1.greeting()

else:
    print("no")
```